# Proving a sequence of functions is an approximation to the identity

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

Define the sequence $\phi_n$ on the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$ (the torus if you will) by:
$$
\phi_n =  c_n (1 + \cos x)^n
$$
Where $c_n$ is a normalizing constant to ensure that $\int_T \phi_n = 1$ for any choice of $n$. I.e $c_n = \int_T (1 + \cos x)^n$. Now, I want to prove this sequence is an approximation to the identity. The main property I must prove is that for any $\delta$ greater than $0$, we have that:
$$
\int_{\{\delta < |x| < \pi\}} \phi_n(x) \mathrm{d}x \to 0
$$
I.e, if we shift a little off from $1$ and take a limit of integrals, all the mass becomes concentrated around $0$, as we would think happens in an approximation to the identity. My main strategy for the proof was to do the following. First, write:
$$
(1 + \cos x)^n = 2^{n} \cos^{2n} \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)
$$
using trigonometric identities. Then we see that $\cos^{2n} \left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \to 0$ pointwise for any $x \neq 0$. Moreover, if we have for fixed $x_0$ that:

$$
\left|\cos^{2n} \left(\frac{x_0}{2}\right)\right|<\epsilon
$$
Then we see that $x > x_0$ implies:
$$
\left|\cos^{2n} \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right|<\epsilon
$$
Hence, given any $\delta > 0$, we can take $N$ such that $n > N$ implies: 
$$
\left|\cos^{2n} \left(\frac{\delta}{2}\right)\right|<\epsilon
$$
So that for any $x$ with $|x| > \delta$ (exploiting symmetry of cosine) we have that:
$$
\left|\cos^{2n} \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right|<\epsilon
$$
And hence:
$$
\int_{\{\delta\} < |x|<\pi} \cos^{2n} \left(\frac{x}{2}\right) < 2(\pi - \delta)\epsilon \to 0
$$
So that the LHS becomes arbitrarily small and converges to $0$. However, I am having issues dealing with the normalizing factor. Namely, we have:
$$
 \int_{\{\delta < |x| < \pi\}} \phi_n(x) \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{\int_{[-\pi,\pi]} 2^{n} \cos^{2n} \left( \frac{x}{2}\right) \mathrm{d}x} \int_{\{\delta < |x| < \pi\}} 2^{n} \cos^{2n} \left( \frac{x}{2}\right)\mathrm{d}x  
$$
The $2^n$ powers cancel, so we have:
$$
\frac{\int_{\{\delta < |x| < \pi\}}  \cos^{2n} \left( \frac{x}{2}\right)\mathrm{d}x}{\int_{[-\pi,\pi]}  \cos^{2n} \left( \frac{x}{2}\right) \mathrm{d}x}
$$
And the numerator of this expression tends to $0$, by my previous argument. However, how can I deal with the normalizing integrals? How do I make sure they do not go to $0$, and if they do (I am fairly sure they do), how can I rigorize the fact that the numerator converges to $0$ faster?

Comment: you mean $\cos^{2n}\frac{x}2\to 0$ pointwise for any $x\neq 0$, not $x\neq 1$.

Comment: Thank you, I've edited that.

Comment: Surely it's becoming more like a _Dirac delta_ function az n→∞ ?

Comment: @ambretteorrisey yes that's what I mean by an approximation to an identity

Comment: Good good! It's _absolutely clear_ now. And there's an infinitude of similar ways of constructing the _Dirac delta_ function; and you can get |x| by lim{a→∞}(1/a)ln(cosh(ax)): & _all kinds_ of other lovely things!

Comment: Got another one you might like: this one tends to the _sharp-cornered-sigmoid_ function (by which I mean y=-1 for x≤1; y=x for -1<x<1; y=+1 for x≥1) as a →∞ : (ln(1+exp(a(1+x)))-ln(1+exp(a(1-x))))/a-x.

Comment: I have just made a post about this: hopefully it will turn-out interesting!

Comment: In your first sentence, the "torus" should be plainly a "cylinder".

Comment: @JeanMarie it's my textbook's notation. Apologies

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the graph of $f(x) = 1+\cos x$ you can intuitively guess that with the powers $f^n$ the mass of the integral will "bunch up" around $x=0$. Points closer to 0 will shoot up faster than points further away (basically because if a>b then $a^n >>b^n$ as n grows large). Here's a way to make that precise:

Let $f(x)$ be positive and strictly decreasing on $[0,\pi]$. We can compare $\int_{[0,\delta]} f^n(x) \,dx$ to $\int_{[\delta,\pi]} f^n(x)\, dx$ by taking their ratio and showing
$$
\frac{\int_{[0,\delta]} f^n(x) \,dx}{\int_{[\delta,\pi]} f^n(x) \,dx} \rightarrow +\infty
$$

By choosing a fixed $0<\epsilon<\delta$ we have that the numerator is at least $\int_{[0,\epsilon]} f^n(x) \,dx$ and this is at least $\epsilon f(\epsilon)^n$ (both of these fact follow since $f\geq 0$ and $f$ is decreasing.
Similarly the denominator is less than $(\pi-\delta)f(\delta)^n$. Since
$$
\frac{\epsilon f(\epsilon)^n}{(\pi-\delta)f(\delta)^n} \rightarrow \infty
$$
we have our result.

Now to apply this result to your problem, you can choose $f(x) = \cos^2(\frac{x}{2})$ as in your last line. You can invert the limit above going to $\infty$ and do one more comparison:

$$
\frac{\int_{[\delta,\pi]} f^n(x) \,dx}{\int_{[0,\pi]} f^n(x) \,dx} \leq \frac{\int_{[\delta,\pi]} f^n(x) \,dx}{\int_{[0,\delta]} f^n(x) \,dx} \rightarrow 0
$$

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the normalising factor explicitly: $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi(1+\cos x)^n\,\mathrm{d}x = 2^{-n}\binom{2n}{n+1}\cdot 2\pi\sim 2^n\cdot\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{n\pi}}$$
where the last asymptotic is by Stirling's formula.  On the other hand, for $\delta<\lvert x\rvert<\pi$, we have $\cos^{2n}\frac{x}{2}<\cos^{2n}\frac\delta2\leq\exp(-cn\delta^2)$, some $c>0$.  So
$$
\frac{\int_{\delta<\lvert x\rvert<\pi}(1+\cos x)^n\,\mathrm{d}x}{\int_{-\pi}^\pi(1+\cos x)^n\,\mathrm{d}x}\lesssim\frac{2^n\exp(-cn\delta^2)\cdot 2\pi}{2^n\cdot{2\pi}/{\sqrt{n\pi}}}\sim\exp(-cn\delta^2)\sqrt{n\pi}\to 0
$$